# how can i solve this? Python cantools key error regarding id

Tags: python, can-bus

I am trying to decode a can message via `cantools`.

```
for ii in range(len(dbcfiles)):
    databases.append(cantools.db.load_file(dbcfiles[ii]))
    
db = cantools.db.Database()

for database in databases:
    db.messages.extend(database.messages)

decoded_mess = []

with can.BLFReader(logfile) as can_log:
    for msg in can_log:
            print(msg.data)
            print(db.decode_message(msg.arbitration_id, msg.data))

print(msg)
# Timestamp: 1610115116.731417        ID: 0036    S                DLC:  8    c0 08 7e 08 a9 0d 0b 0f     Channel: 24
```

The problem is that the last line `db.decode_message(msg.arbitration_id, msg.data)` produces a `Key Error: 54 (thats decimal of 36)`. I got the error for every msg for different id's and i know the id's are in the dbc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After your second for-loop call

```
db.refresh()
```

From the cantools docu:

> refresh()
> Refresh the internal database state.
>
> This method must be called after modifying any message in the database to refresh the internal lookup tables used when encoding and decoding messages.